# Android soap(ksoap2) service invalid int

Tags: android, ksoap2

I am using soap services in my application for getting data from the api

https://www.interserver.net/

and the response from the api includes an interger value and it is in form "ITO-207-18564", and during getting response app crashes with exception

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "ITO-207-18564"
```

I know the problem but as the response is coming from the interserver api and before I can get it, app crashes, how can I handle this crash on my side? Thanks for your time and help.

here is my code.

```
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new      
    SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        // Invoke web service
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION + "api_openTicket", envelope);
        // Get the response

        SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
        String status_return = response.getProperty(0).toString();
        String status_text = response.getProperty(1).toString();
        String ticket_reference_id = String.valueOf(response.getProperty(2));

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

debug report
[image]

Comment: Add the logcat too.

Comment: @KNeerajLal I have posted the debug report

Comment: Debug report is the complete output of `e.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: yes it is the complete output of e.printStackTrace().

Comment: So where is it? I cant see it in the question. The image shows only the error as given in the question.

Comment: During debugging when the control goes to catch block on "e.printstackTrace()" as result of invalid integer from the response this is all that appears in the debug section, the two blue lines in the image from the code section and the debug section are showing what i am trying to say.

Comment: See what happens in the logcat if you execute `e.printStackTrace()`.